# Changing button width on click but not container

Tags: css, button, sass

I am trying to create button when the user clicks down, the inner container changes width but the outer container as a whole (black background) doesnt change width. What i currently have is close, but when a user clicks the shadow changes.

Snippet: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/ncanarelli/cj9Lhq20/)

[image: Desired button changes]

html:

```
<button class="btn btn__primary" type="button">
    Continue
    <i class="fa-solid fa-sparkles m-l-8px"></i>
</button>
```

scss:

```
.btn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 12px;
    font-family: $aeonik_bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 0.55px;
    border: 1.5px solid $button_border_color;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px 1.5px $button_border_color;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 150ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;

    &:active {
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: #5a44ff;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-duration: 150ms;
    }
    &:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: #5a44ff;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-duration: 150ms;
    }
    &:disabled {
        background: #d9dbe9;
        border: 1.5px solid #d9dbe9;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: default;
    }

    &__primary {
        background-color: $purple_resting;
        color: white;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-duration: 150ms;

        &:not(:disabled) {
            &:hover {
                background-color: #6955ff;
                border: 1.5px solid #170f49;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-shadow: -0.5px 0.5px 0px 1px $button_border_color;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
                animation-duration: 150ms;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you create a snippet ?

Comment: Yup doing it now!

Comment: @dippas original post edited with snippet link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what you were trying to do with the animations so I came up with a different approach using a inset box shadow and padding on a child span with transition.

If you want to change the sizing of box shadow then you just need to add the pixels used in the box shadow to the left and bottom padding of the button and then do the reverse on active e.g.

If the box shadow was `inset 4px -4px 0 #000000` and the padding of the button was `16px`.

Then the padding of the button would be `padding: 16px 16px 20px 20px;` and on active it would be `padding: 20px 20px 16px 16px;`

```css
.btn {
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 2px -2px 0 #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 0 #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 2px -2px 0 #000000;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn > span {
   padding: 8px 8px 10px 10px;
   transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
   display: block;
}

.btn:active {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 0 #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 0 #000000;
}

.btn:active > span {
   padding: 10px 10px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn__primary" type="button">
      <span>Continue <i class="fa-solid fa-sparkles m-l-8px"></i></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh i see what you did, this nailed it thank you @WizardCoder

Answer (score 0):

You'll add a border to the left and bottom side, and then reduce them when the button is active

```scss
.container {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.btn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 0.55px;
    border: 1.5px solid #092c4c;
    border-left: 3px solid #092c4c;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #092c4c;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 150ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;

    &:active {
        border-left: 0 solid #092c4c;
        border-bottom: 0 solid #092c4c;
        background-color: #5a44ff;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-duration: 150ms;
    }
    &:focus {
        background-color: #5a44ff;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-duration: 150ms;
    }
    &:disabled {
        background: #d9dbe9;
        border: 1.5px solid #d9dbe9;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: default;
    }

    &__primary {
        background-color: #7a6af6;
        color: white;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-duration: 150ms;

        &:not(:disabled) {
            &:hover {
                background-color: #6955ff;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
                animation-duration: 150ms;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it is helpful <3

Comment: this is really close, but when its clicked the height of the button changes thus shifting the content below it. I'd like the height and width of the button to stay the same at all times, but only the width of the purple changing.

Comment: oh right... I forgot this point

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding, you are trying a neubrutalistic button. Here is my approach.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
}
.btn{
  --off-x: 3px;
  --off-y: 4px;
  background: orchid;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: calc(var(--off-x, 0)*-1) var(--off-y, 0) black;
  transform: translate(var(--off-x, 0), calc(var(--off-y, 0)*-1));
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.btn:active{
  box-shadow: 0 0;
  transform: translate(0);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Continue</button>
```

Comment: I'm not actually looking for the pink to move, instead id like the left and bottom grow in size to the box shadow.